# The variable sum in the while loop is concating and not adding

Tags: java, concatenation

Here's my code:

```
public static int baseB2int(String number, int base)
   {
      int product = 0;
      int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
      int sum;
      int i = number.length();
      int[] theNumber = new int[i];

      for (int j = 0; j < number.length(); j++)
      {
         System.out.println("the length of number is " + number.length());
         theNumber[j] = num%base;
         System.out.println("theNumber["+j+"] is " + theNumber[j]);
         num = num/base;
         System.out.println("the num is "+num);
      }

      sum = theNumber[i - 1];
      System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);

      while (i > 0)
      {
         product = sum * base;
         System.out.println("The product in the while loop is " + product);
         System.out.println("theNumber[previous]" + theNumber[i-1]);
         sum = product + theNumber[i-1];
         System.out.println("the sum in the while loop is " + sum);
         i--;
      }

      return product;
   }
```

Comment: Please reformat your code.

Comment: Why do you think sum is "not adding"?  What arguments are you using for `number` and `base`, and what is the output?